# Kramdown with rogue didn't generate <pre> wrapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, kramdown, rouge

This is from my pry console:

````
> input = <<-HEREDOC
* # Header 1
* ## Header 2
*
* ```
* def hello
*   puts "hello world"
* end
* ```
* HEREDOC
=> "# Header 1\n## Header 2\n\n```\ndef hello\n  puts \"hello world\"\nend\n```\n"
> Kramdown::Document.new(input, input: "GFM", syntax_highlighter: "rouge").to_html
=> "<h1 id=\"header-1\">Header 1</h1>\n<h2 id=\"header-2\">Header 2</h2>\n\n<div class=\"highlighter-rouge\">def hello\n  puts \"hello world\"\nend\n</div>\n"
````

As you can see, the html generated for the code block doesn't contain any `<pre>` code wrapper. But if I removed `rouge` option and use `coderay`, it works beautifully.

```
> Kramdown::Document.new(input, input: "GFM").to_html
=> "<h1 id=\"header-1\">Header 1</h1>\n<h2 id=\"header-2\">Header 2</h2>\n\n<pre><code>def hello\n  puts \"hello world\"\nend\n</code></pre>\n"
```

Any idea what's wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It works okay for me. What version of kramdown are you using?

Comment: Found out it's because of the `rogue` gem version. I need to use version < 2.0.0

Comment: When you post code please strip out pry's line prompt. Not only is it distracting, but everyone who wants to run your code must do that.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Noted. I'll edit this one and remember to do it next time

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the `rouge` gem version. I need to change it to < `v2.0.0`. And now I'm using:

- kramdown v1.13.1
- rouge v1.11.1